# active record through troubles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three models.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :zones
  has_many :iteractions, :through => :zones
end

class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :iteractions
end

class Iteraction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :count, :itime
  belongs_to :zone
  belongs_to :location, :through => :zone
end
```

So and I trying to install rails_admin
Is says to me "Unknown key: through(Argument Error)"

Where is error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `belongs_to` association cannot have a `:through` option. Instead you can use `has_one :location, :through => :zone`